# php where is my percentage of the day being calculated wrong?

Tags: php

I been trying to fix this php percentage calculator of the day...basically right now here is about 230pm and I am getting 73% of the day completed....it should be more like 60% of the day. Here is the code:

```
 $now = time();
 $today = strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
 $seconds = $now - $today;
 $day = 24*60*60;   
 $percent = $seconds / $day*100;
```

I attempted to write my own version but I am getting 100% of the day...Here is the code:

```
 $todaysTime = time();
 $todaysStart = time()-86400;
 $todayCalc = $todaysTime - $todaysStart;
 $dayPhpOne = 24*60*60; 
 $percentDay = $todayCalc / $dayPhpOne*100;
```

It is done in php where am I messing up my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$percentDay = time() % 86400 / 864;
```

**Edit**

From the comments I take, that I didn't elaborate on time zones. Let me make clear, that this is meant to be **UTC** day percent.

Comment: What about timezones?

Comment: That assumes that midnight aligns with the multiples of 68400 - which would be false for any number of reasons - timezones, daylight savings, history, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited the answer to point the UTC-based calculation out more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does respect timezone and other time-related complexities:

```
$d = new DateTime();

$h = $d->format('H');
$m = $d->format('i');
$s = $d->format('s');

$currentSecond = $h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s;

$midnight = new DateTime($d->format('Y-m-d'), $d->getTimezone());
$tomorrow = clone $midnight;
$tomorrow = $tomorrow->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

$secondsToday = $tomorrow->getTimestamp() - $midnight->getTimestamp();

$percent = $currentSecond / $secondsToday * 100;

var_dump($percent);
```

If necessary - it's possible to specify a particular timezone to be used as a second `DateTime` constructor argument.

Comment: dam so close to 10k you must taste it ;-)

Comment: But this would still calculate a “wrong” percentage for those days that are not 86400 seconds long …

Comment: Dam 74% really.... I was getting 74 with last one....ehhh basically what I was getting....

Comment: @CBroe: now it does take it into account

Comment: @user3561965: you can modify `$d = new DateTime();` to `$d = new DateTime('2014-05-03 09:00:00');` to see what result will be tomorrow morning

Comment: @user3561965: also open `phpinfo();` and check what timezone is set by default

Comment: @Dagon: your (?) serial upvoting was reversed - it's not that easy to fool SO :-)